# Sort Aggregation on decay function in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

> this is my decay function with aggregation for getting topics count.

```
GET goal,user,summary,tip/_search
    {
            "query": {
                "function_score": {
                    "exp": {
                        "created": {
                              "origin": "now", 
                              "scale": "1d",
                              "decay" : 0.5 
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "aggs" : {
              "topics": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "topics.keyword"
                }
              }
            }
        }
```

I want my answer order by created date.
It is searching in the whole index. i want topics which are trending on current day.